# Fastboot flash Pixel 4a device corruption

Tags: adb, fastboot, lineageos, google-pixel-4a

I tried out lineage on my pixel 4a and it went south
Right now I'm trying to flash with ADB the original sunfish IMG but now there is no recovery image. It just says the device is corrupt
The boot loader and OEM are both unlocked

Is there a for sure method to flashing the stock images back to the phone?

Comment: Boot into bootloader and use fastboot for flashing. The original flash scripts provided by Google AFAIR use fastboot.

Comment: @Robert that's the one I used. I used the flash-all script and now I can't get into recovery nor boot

Comment: @Robert https://developers.google.com/android/images